# How to pass values to a variadic parameter in a func from a variadic argument

Tags: go

The SQL library func QueryContext takes variadic parameter for the where clause. I would like to create a helper function that takes variadic parameter and send that to QueryContext call.

Here is my code snippet:

```
func GenericDBSelect(ctx context.Context, qry string, params ...string) (*sql.Rows, error) {
    // format the connectstr
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", connectstr)

    if err != nil || db == nil {
        msg := "could not get db connection. Is DB available?"
        return nil, fmt.Errorf(msg)
    }

    rows, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, qry, params)

    if err != nil {
        msg := fmt.Sprintf("Could not prep query = %v, params = %v. Error = %v ", qry, params, err)
    
        return nil, fmt.Errorf(msg)
    }

    return rows, err
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
rows, err := GenericDBSelect(ctx, qry, param1, param2)
```

When I run this code, it throws the following error:

> SQL: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type []string, a slice of string

The problem seems to be that the params in GenericDBSelect is received as []string instead of ...string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these two changes:

- Declare GenericDBSelect to take the same type of variadic argument as QueryContext. This allows `params` to be passed through with no conversion.

  ```
    func GenericDBSelect(ctx context.Context, 
         qry string, params ...any) (*sql.Rows, error) {
  ```
- Pass the variadic arguments to QueryContext using the `...` syntax:

  ```
   rows, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, qry, params...)
  ```

See [Passing arguments to ... parameters](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters) for more information.